# How can I create a way to temporarily block IPs from accessing a form too many times?

Tags: php, forms, access-control

I'm looking for ideas/ways to temporarily block an ip from accessing a webpage on my site/form many times.

The limit should be something like, no more than 5 times in 1 day to the webpage/form otherwise it should show a simple text message like "Too many request from your ip, please try again later, if you feel like this is wrong, please contact us".

I hope for something simple via PHP but I'm open to anything really. I'm not really sure how to work with databases and cookies but I'm sure I can read up on it.

Comment: What form of persistance are you using? You will need to store some state from page load to page load on the server side (cookies don't really solve the problem - a clear cache will get the user right back in).

Comment: you could, it would be easy to get around, not work for every one, and not really achieve much, so what the problem your actully trying to fix?

Comment: Ah, I'm not really using anything. That's true, but it might stop simple bots maybe?

Comment: use a robots.txt file to stop nice bots, there's no reliably way to stop not nice bots, its the nature of  the www.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and quick solution :

1. Create table `id, url, user_ip, request_number, date`
2. Check in db by url,date,user_ip and request_number>5 and block or not this request. 
   If not use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE request_number = request_number+1`

Also you can use blocking on web-server side. For example, nginx allows to add ips for denying on fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set cookies with a timestamp and number of submits, and check the timestamp against the current time.

Cookies can be cleared though, so you might want to back it up with storing IP's and timestamps in a mysql db. And on visit, check the ip in the db against current time and number of submits.

Comment: Ah alright, that sounds good. How would I go about doing that, setting the cookies and entering the data in the mysql database (Sorry I'm really new to it)?

My form's method is POST and is relatively simple, if that's any help.

Comment: your protecting a form from being posted by bots? that's a different issue, add a CAPTCHA

Answer (score 0):

Use a table with 2 columns IPAddress and Date

check it like

```
SELECT COUNT(\*) c FROM table WHERE ipaddress = 'ipaddress' AND ipdate = 'date("Y-m-d")'

if c greater then 4, 

<\? die("your message"); ?>

else
insert into table VALUES ('ipadress', 'date(Y-m-d)');
```